# Enable CORS in lumen

Tags: api, cors, lumen

I have API developed using lumen. I can get request using postman. But when request using Jquery.ajax it is not working. So I need to know how to enable CORS in lumen API.

Answer (score 63):

Consider creating a `CorsMiddleware.php` file with the following code. Find detail [here.](https://gist.github.com/danharper/06d2386f0b826b669552)

```
  <?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class CorsMiddleware
    {
     /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
        {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

After saving it in your middleware folder, enable it by adding it to your `bootstap/app.php` file, on the list of you middleware like this

```
$app->middleware([
    ...
    App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class // Add this

]);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: no idea why the  error  still showing after adding using the package `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api//stocks/company/info?company=. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)`

Comment: I have added your suggestion corsmiddleware in my project, but still getting same error, any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Sometime CORS error message could be generated when your api has an error. In such a case, the message is not due to the lack of CORS setting but due to the fact that there is a bug in your api that needs to be fix. Try to test you api properly independently before integrating it into your client app.

Comment: If you still have a problem * Enable Headers and CORS in Apache* --> https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: This code is not working on Lumen 10

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend using the CORS package by Barry vd. Heuvel:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors#lumen

It has configurable and supports Pre-flight request handling for ajax.

Answer (score -1):

[@The Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2773684/the-oracle) answer works properly to many, the problem is what surfaces as CORS problem might be something else. Please be informed that PHP errors in your code could emerge as CORS problem but it's actually not. Make use of different tools to troubleshoot if it's CORS or not.

1. For example to prove if it's CORS use postman, ex. GET method should work properly because postman is exempted from CORS as it's not a browser. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for reference
2. You may sometimes drop your API url in the browser to check for such errors, if it's a backend error or specifically PHP error it normally displays/outputs on the browser with details like what caused the error and on which line etc. Enable Debugging in PHP if you think it's not enabled.

Comment: Although nicely worded and a good suggestion, this doesn't really answer the question. Ishan was specifically asking about a CORS issue. Consider adding this as a comment instead.

Comment: Understood Lewis, thanks

Answer (score -1):

For Enable CORS policy inside Lumen you need to add a package via composer

Run the command for install cors package : `composer require nordsoftware/lumen-cors`

After that you need to configure service in bootstrap/app.php : `$app->register('Nord\Lumen\Cors\CorsServiceProvider');`

And Last one for middleware registration for application use :

```
$app->middleware([
'Nord\Lumen\Cors\CorsMiddleware', // top of all middleware
.......                           // rest of middlewares
]);
```

Comment: I tried by this package and it works fine

Comment: I tried the package and it says that a Service cannot be instantiated when using the middleware and this cors package is abandoned

Comment: @MinhNgo I think you can not use this package for latest version of Lumen.