# Frontend gets Error 401 from Backend in CORS request - apache/php insufficiently configured?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

I have a frontend, running on most recent vue on port 5000.
Then I have my backend, running on most recent lumen on port 8080.
Both are on my localmachine. Later in production, they will be separated on two virtual machines.

Right now, when sending an http request from the frontend to the backend, I get the following error to my devConsole (NOT the vue devtools, but the usual firefox/chrome devtools console!):

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
```

The function returning the axios object executing the http request looks like this:

```
function fetchData(method, slug, payload) {
  return axios[method](`${API_ENDPOINT}${slug}`, payload);
}
```

The call looks like this:

```
fetchData(METHOD_POST, USER_LIST, "someToken").then((res)=>{
        return res
      })
```

`METHOD_POST` contains the string `post` and `USER_LIST` contains the string `/user/show_data` which is used to further specify the URL. In my Lumen backend, it accesses the following route:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() use ($router){

    $router->post('/show_data', 'UserController@getData');

});
```

The route and the respective controller work, I've tested it with RESTClient https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/restclient/

I think that syntaxwise, everything is fine. Also, the token wasnt expired when I used it, I checked this multiple times. 
So I think that it might be connected to the CORS-Policy of the apache and/or php.
Im running apache and php from the latest XAMPP dist.

Still, I'm not entirely sure if thats it, especially since this is the first time that I connect a backend using lumen and a frontend using vue.js.

EDIT: I managed to activate "withCredentials" for my axios object by changing the function body to:

```
  axios.defaults.headers.withCredentials = true;
  return axios[method](`${API_ENDPOINT}${slug}`, payload);
```

However, now the CORS problem turns up ^^ 
When sending the http request, I get these error messages to my console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/user/show_data' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And

```
xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:8080/user/show_data net::ERR_FAILED
```

And

```
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at t.exports (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d.onerror (xhr.js:83)
```

What should I do?

EDIT2:
I now added the following lines to my httpd.conf and restarted apache and lumenproject:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Max-Age: 360
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
</IfModule>
```

I also tried out explicitely specifying the origin to

```
http://localhost:8080
```

and

```
http://localhost:5000
```

But it didnt help. The errormessage remains the same.

Comment: Sounds like it might not be sending some necessary auth credentials with the request, like a session cookie or something. Try and add `withCredentials: true` to your axios request options.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the tip, how can I do this syntaxwise? Can you give me an example what the notation for such a modified axios object would look like? Ideally using the same approach with axios[method]..., but if thats not possible I'll also take anything else :)

Comment: Using `axios[method]` makes rather little sense here to begin with, I think - because depending on the method, the parameters you need to pass are different. `get` takes `url` and `config`, `post` takes `url`, `data` and `config`. You would at least need to make two different kinds of calls inside your `fetchData` function, depending on the method. `withCredentials` belongs into the `config` in any case.

Comment: @CBroe see my appended Edit, I made some progress and ran into the next issue :D

Comment: The _preflight_ request is made using the OPTIONS method - but it looks like you are currently only handling POST requests with your router setup.

Comment: @CBroe but why is it using OPTIONS? Oo 
Besides I think back when I did the same without frameworks, the pre-flight error also occurred, but I resolved the issue without addressing it directly. I think it was only tied to the CORS policy and how I configured it in the apache httpd.conf

Comment: @CBroe I added my changes to the httpd.conf of my apache. I appended these changes via Edit to my OP, if it helps.

Comment: _“but why is it using OPTIONS?”_ - because that is how CORS works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: @CBroe Okay, then what can I do in my router to somehow handle this OPTIONS Request? Do I understand correctly that before my POST Request is sent, an OPTIONS Request is sent "pre-flight", before the "actual request" so to speak?

Comment: Yes, the browser automatically makes this pre-flight request, when necessary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448134/enable-cors-in-lumen

Answer (score 1):

Most browser will block you anyway if your backend allow any host.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

You are also missin a semi-colon

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

Try

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "yourorigindomain.com"
```